# Print RDLC file without showing print preview from Form button click

Tags: printing, reportviewer, rdlc

I've got a C#4.0 WinForm with a button click for Printing. In the Form Load event, I populate a custom object and stick that object into a list of that object. The object maps directly to the RDLC as a datasource and if I use the Report Viewer, I can see my RDLC file populated correctly. I found a link at MSDN to do this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx), but it blows up on the Export method.

Does anyone know of any good examples of how to print an RDLC file without using ReportViewer to preview the file? I just want to hit a button and have my List bind to the RDLC file (which I've already got working) and print directly to the printer.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so the link at [Walkthrough: Printing a Local Report without Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx) does actually work perfectly for my need to print a RDLC file without popping up the Print dialogue box. The mistake I made was naming my `ReportDataSource`. As in the example, MSDN names its `ReportDataSource` as "Sales" which matches the name of the `DataSet` in the RDLC XML codebehind. I had made the mistake of naming my `ReportDataSource` "Sale" which was causing the two not to be in sync and not print.

Problem solved!

Comment: Ouch -- that would do it.  Glad you figured it out!

Comment: I have encountered a problem with this sample code from MSDN. Everything works if I click my Print button (i.e. execute the code frmo the sample) but when I try to click to Print again (within 10 seconds or so), I get a message saying that the EMF file that gets generated in the CreateStream method is in use (The process cannot access the file 'Sales.EMF' because it is being used by another process.) and I get an IOException. How can I avoid this? I will have my user Printing items faster than the file can be released from lock.

Comment: Okay fixed it. The problem was that MSDN's example is a single class that is meant to be executed once and IDisposable is implemented. In my case, I made the class a helper file that I instantiate once per form load, so Dispose() never gets called until the form's lifecycle ends. So, instead of implementing IDisposable, I instead make the Dispose() method private and simply call it explicitly after Print() executes. This way, I Dispose() the streams that are generated and I don't get IOExceptions.

Comment: can we use it for web applications using IIS ???? in Debug Mode it works fine but when we host the application in IIS it stops working and give no exception.